# Turn off form fields autocomplete on browser back button for Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, forms, autocomplete

There are some questions that explain how to turn off the autocomplete feature for form fields however I have a specific problem here:

I've set the `autocomplete="off"` to both the the `<form>` and all form fields. I want to prevent the browser from prefilling the fields when the user returns from the forms target page to the original page (that contains the form) by using the browser back button. The form fields use some jQuery UI widgets that don't work with prefilled values. It's necessary that the user interacts with the form before submitting it.

This works as expected in Firefox, Chrome, Safari. However it doesn't work in Internet Explorer (I've tested versions 8 and 9). IE still fills out the fields when returning to the page via the browser's back button.

This is a static HTML page so I'm not able to perform some backend actions like for example setting random form field names/IDs.

What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done. Maybe try emptying every input field on document ready (something like `$(":input").val("");`)

Comment: Hm, that's not an optimal solution. I forgot to mention that the form fields contain some initial, descriptive values like "Your firstname" that of course should be retained.

Comment: @Sven input elements have a `defaultValue` property that *should* contain the initial value. You could try setting them to that.

Comment: @Sven - even better, look into the `placeholder` attribute for input fields. It's explicitly designed for that kind of info text inside a field. It's an HTML5 feature, so older browsers may not support it, but there are Javascript/JQuery scripts that will use the placeholder attribute if it isn't supported by the browser.

Comment: I tried to use the `placeholder` attribute and evaluated some jQuery plugins that bring this feature to non-HTML5 browsers. However none of these plugins worked flawlessly. For example executing `val("")` removed the placeholder text in non-HTML5 browsers whereas the placeholder was retained in "standard" browsers. I guess this has something to do with the fact that the plugins use the `value` attribute as a workaround. I'm now using a combination of `placeholder` and setting the values of all input fields to their placeholder value on page load.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        var f = document.getElementById('MyTextBox');
        f.textContent = ""; // or default values
    }
</script>
```

Have you tried this to unload the data when leaving the page so it's not there when coming back?

I have the same problem unfortunately I can't get this solution going in ASP.NET.